# String.split() in elixir placing a empty string at the end of the list of substrings in the output

Tags: split, elixir

I am new to [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/). I am trying a basic operation to [split](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#split/3) the string which is as follows

```
String.split("Awesome","");
```

According to the [elixir document](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#split/3), it should [split](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#split/3) the string based on the pattern provided. The `output` I get is as follows

```
["A", "w", "e", "s", "o", "m", "e", ""]
```

I was expecting an `output` as follows

```
["A", "w", "e", "s", "o", "m", "e"]
```

My `Elixir` and `Elang` version are as follows

```
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]
Elixir 1.5.1
```

I am unable to understand why an `empty string` is added at the `end` of the `list of substrings` in the output. Can somebody let me know why I am getting the above output and help with the expected output?

Comment: Not an answer but you probably want to use `String.codepoints/1` or `String.graphemes/1` to split a string like this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I guess it's the expected behaviour. The [link you provided](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#split/3) also says the following thing:

> Empty strings are only removed from the result if the `:trim` option is set to true.

It's in one of the examples with the solution:

> Splitting on empty patterns returns graphemes:

```
iex> String.split("abc", "")
["a", "b", "c", ""]

iex> String.split("abc", "", trim: true)
["a", "b", "c"]
```

If you're wondering what "graphemes" are, the Elixir documentation has this explained too at the beginning of the [String documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html).

Finally, there are two other useful functions if you want to dig into graphemes: `String.codepoints/1` and `String.graphemes/1`. For example:

```
iex> noel = "noe\u0308l"
"noël"
iex> String.codepoints(noel)
["n", "o", "e", "̈", "l"]
iex> String.graphemes(noel)
["n", "o", "ë", "l"]

# Let's try with your example
iex> String.codepoints("Awesome")
["A", "w", "e", "s", "o", "m", "e"]
iex> String.graphemes("Awesome")
["A", "w", "e", "s", "o", "m", "e"]
```